# Using statements / calling Dispose inside static methods

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, memory-leaks, parallel-processing

I am developing a utility class that contains static methods that will be frequently called by multiple threads. I am noticing that memory use is growing over time, so it seems to me that I have some memory leaks.

Here is a simple example of the pattern I am using for these static methods:

```
public static int CreateNewThing(int IDofSomeDBObjectHoldingInfoToCreateNewThing)
{
    using(SomeDBContext context = new SomeDBContext(connectionString))
    {
        SomeDBObjectHoldingInfoToCreateNewThing createNewThingyInfo = context.SomeDBObjectsHoldingInfoToCreateNewThing.First(obj => obj.ID == IDofSomeDBObjectHoldingInfoToCreateNewThing);
        // Do some stuff to create the new object
        // Return the ID of the newly created thingy...
        return theNewThingThatWasCreated.ID;
     }
}
```

My question is whether using 'using' statements or directly calling Dispose inside static methods actually clears up any memory. Granted, I haven't stated the overall architecture or purpose of this application, but I am also wondering if I'm using the best pattern here. What are the best practices for creating thread-safe utility classes in .NET?

Comment: "I am noticing that memory use is growing over time" -- this doesn't necessarily mean you have a memory leak.  Have you used a profiler to determine this or are you just looking at Task Manager?

Comment: This is a windows service, so I'm really just looking at Task Manager.  I plan on checking it out with a profiler sometime today, but I came here first to see if this was a common occurrence or something that just I am experiencing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am noticing that memory use is growing over time, so it seems to me that I have some memory leaks.

Not necessarily - you'd need to give more data for us to really have a good idea about that.

> My question is whether using 'using' statements or directly calling Dispose inside static methods actually clears up any memory.

`using` statements aren't about cleaning up memory. That's the GC's job. They're about releasing *non-memory* resources. Whether you're in a static method or not is completely irrelevant to whether the `SomeDBContext` ought to be disposed or not.

Comment: I guess what I should ask is whether using 'using' or calling Dispose inside a static method actually does cause the GC to clean up the object.

Comment: @hotSauce.Open: Disposal and garbage collection are *completely separate*, and again, whether you're in a static method or not is irrelevant to that.

Comment: Sounds like there's no need for me to worry about it too much unless it becomes a problem, but it also sounds like I need to further educate myself about memory management in .NET :-)

Comment: Aside from searching for some good information on the subject, do you happen to have any good links I could benefit from?

Answer (score 6):

> My question is whether using 'using' statements or directly calling Dispose inside static methods actually clears up any memory

`using` is just a syntactially simpler way of calling `Dispose`.

```
using(MyClass obj = new MyClass())
{

}
```

is just the same as writing:

```
MyClass obj;
try
{
    obj = new MyClass()
}
finally
{
    ((IDisposable)obj).Dispose();
}
```

Next, does `Dispose` free up memory.  No, it doesn't.  Dispose is designed to release unmanaged resources that won't get cleaned up with then garbage collector releases the memory for this object.  It doesn't actually release the memory for the object any quicker.  Common things that need to be disposed of are network connections (as is the case here) file handles, unmanaged memory created through interopping with another language, etc.

So, why is your memory going up.  In short, it's just the usual behavior.  You are creating objects, they are using memory, so your memory is increasing.  At some point the garbage collector will determine that it needs to perform a collection to free up some memory. (Possibly because the system is running low and it needs more, possibly because it has just been long enough, or whatever other conditions the C# language has specified.  It almost always knows better than you when a collection is really needed.)

So until you have a real problem just don't worry about it, this is normal behavior in a managed language.  If you start running out of memory, or having the memory not go down even when collections *do* occur, then you need to start looking for problems.